# Disable posts generated from image uploads

Tags: posts, images

WordPress generates a post for each image I upload. On my site I got a picture assigned to the header: https://autowaschplatz.at/contact/. The image is separately browsable via https://autowaschplatz.at/person-using-macbook-3747202/. How can I disable/hide this feature so search engines won't find those sites?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this with updates to functions.php as well but the easiest might be to first install Yoast plugin and then use the setting for Attachment URLS that redirect it to the parent post
https://yoast.com/media-attachment-urls/